# PHP DNS lookup script not executing shell command and writing DNS loopup results as expected

Tags: php, shell, dns

I'm thinking I'm close on this script.  I'm now only able to get one line of domain name stuff written out to an output file.  ideally, I want all my array fields written out for all the arrays returned:

```
function getDNS(){      
    if(file_exists($outputFile)){                                                 unlink($outputFile);                              
    }
    $outputFile = 'DNS-Output.csv';     
    $inputFile = fopen('DNS-input.csv','r');
    $output = NULL;
    //make sure we loop through to end of file contents
    $newOutput = 'Domain, IP Address, Exiration Date, Record Type, TTL, Cloud' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= $newOutput;
    while (!feof($inputFile)) {
        $line = fgets($inputFile, 4096); 
        $array = explode(",",$line);
        $result = dns_get_record($array[0], DNS_A + DNS_SOA); // get DNS info
        if ( ! is_array( $result )){
        $results = explode(",",$result);
        }
        print_r($result);
        $whois = shell_exec("whois " . $result[0]['ip'] . " | grep" . " NetName"); 
        $whois = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $whois);
        if ( ! is_array( $whois )){
        $result = explode(",",$whois);
        }
        //if array
         if ( is_array($whois)){
         $whois[0]['host'].", " . PHP_EOL;              // Domain Name
         //print_r($whois); 
        }

        foreach ($whois as $record) {
           $output .=  $record;
          /* $output .=     
           $record['host'].", " .               // Domain Name
           $record['ip'].", ".                   // IP Address
           $record['type'].", ".                 // Type of Record               
           $record['minimum-ttl'].", ".PHP_EOL;       // Minimum TTL
           */
        }
    file_put_contents($outputFile, $output);                // Create CSV File
    }
    //file_put_contents($outputFile, $output);              // Create CSV File
    fclose($inputFile);
    }
```

getDNS();

And here is an example line from the input csv file that I'm doing the lookup off of....

```
somedomain.COM,.com,9/14/06 19:03,9/14/12 19:03,Active,Public,Locked,"ns31.domaincontrol.com(), ns32.domaincontrol.com()",,
```

Looking for the best way to now write the array elements out to their appropriate columns in a csv output file.

Comment: If your input and output files are CSV, use the `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` functions.

Comment: the fgetcsv did not work at all in my case.  I don't know why.  It was just plain wonky.  But the fget method I used instead worked great and it's not the actual issue I'm asking about anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error getting the whois:

```
$whois = shell_exec("whois " . $array[0]['ip'] . " | grep" . " NetName");
```

Should be:

```
$whois = shell_exec("whois " . $result[0]['ip'] . " | grep" . " NetName");
```

After fixing that, I get correct results.

This code seems wrong to me to:

```
if ( ! is_array( $result ))
  $results = explode(",",$result);
```

Should be

```
if ( ! is_array( $result ))
  $result = explode(",",$result);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had already found and fixed the command line error on the whois.  The ! is_array observation is perplexing as I can't see the difference between my code and yours.  Maybe I'm tired...

Comment: It is the 's' from results should be result

Answer (score 1):

You're using the incorrect first dimension when writing the output. dns_get_record() retrieves multiple DNS records grouped by that initial dimension, which you're treating as a column instead.

So rather than this:

```
    $whois[0]['host'].", " . PHP_EOL;               // Domain Name
    $whois[2]['ip'].", ".                   // IP Address
    $whois[5]['type'].", ".                 // Type of Record               
    $result[1]['minimum-ttl'].", ".         // Minimum TTL
    $whois[1] . PHP_EOL;                    // Cloud
```

You want something like this:

```
foreach ($whois as $record) {
    $record['host'].", " . PHP_EOL;               // Domain Name
    $record['ip'].", ".                   // IP Address
    $record['type'].", ".                 // Type of Record               
    $record['minimum-ttl'].", ".PHP_EOL         // Minimum TTL
}
```

Comment: What are those lines supposed to do? They don't assign or print the fields of `$record`. In the original code I suspect they're supposed to all be part of one big big assignment to `$output`, but there's a `;` after `PHP_EOL` that ends it, and everything after that gets ignored.

Comment: Yes.  My bad, they are the big assignment to the output.  In other words, output .= $record....  etc. So I found your comment to be very helpful.  I KNEW I was missing one more loop through stuff.  However, I'm only now getting one line written to my output file.  I'm going to see if I can edit this question with the new code or if it's more appropriate to open a new question with the now more complete code.